# current_user_can() returning true for capability when the user and role do not have the capability

Tags: users, user-roles, capabilities, permissions

I've been trying to remove the "Customize" from the admin bar by removing the capability from the 'tt_editor' role by adding this to the bottom of the init action function:

```
$editor = get_role('tt_editor');
$editor->remove_cap('customize');
```

This seems to remove the capability, but at the beginning of `wp_admin_bar_customize_menu()` in wp-includes/admin-bar.php `current_user_can('customize')` still returns true.

I've even tried moving it to the beginning of the admin bar function directly before it calls `current_user_can()`.

I've even tried removing the capability from the current user, that doesn't work either.

I fail to see how even with all these different methods, current_user_can() still returns true:

```
global $wp_roles;
$wp_roles->remove_cap('tt_editor', 'customize');

$role = get_role('tt_editor');
$role->remove_cap('customize');

wp_get_current_user()->remove_cap('customize');

var_dump(current_user_can('customize')); // STILL RETURNS TRUE?
```

I suppose this could be a bug in Wordpress Core? We're on version 5.8.6.

As a workaround I'm using `$wp_admin_bar->remove_menu('customize')` but I would like to do it by removing the capability really.

Comment: it could be that your user has the capability to do that, not just the role, or that your user has multiple capabilities. Note that you are removing the capability from the role, but you are not testing that it was removed from that role in any of your code, you're instead testing if it was removed from the ***user*** not the ***role***

Comment: also if you are a super admin then it doesn't matter which role you have